# Does it look bad if none of my recommendation letters for grad school are from past professors?

Tags: graduate-school, recommendation-letter

I want two of my letters to come from individuals I did research with (at different times) but neither has taught me or has a full professor title - one is adjunct and the other is a scientist at a university-affiliated lab. I think my academic advisor (the schoolwide kind not the department-specific kind) would write the best third letter and it might provide a different perspective from the other two.

Is it better to forego one of these recommendations from people who know me really well in favor of a professor who doesn't know me as well?

Answer (score 5):

Letters from "lower-status" people but who've really seen you doing the thing (rather than taking classes in "the thing") are infinitely better than (routine) letters from routine-coursework instructors, regardless of their status.

Answer (score 1):

You want writers who can provide a compelling letter. I advise students to ask the professor first 'do you feel you can write a compelling letter?'  Usually they'll tell you if not. I also recommend putting together a prospectus of your accomplishments to help them write one. Having a writer with full professor status (vs assistant or associate) is less important than the content.